# Workflow Error - Failed on start

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow

I am using SharePoint 2010. Workflows are getting failed.
It shows Status:**"Failed on Start"** and below is the error message in workflow history list:

**Please note:**

The workflows are OOB approval workflow and not designer workflow. The library has 6 workflows and all the workflows are failing while starting.

[image]

Comment: What steps have you performed so far to troubleshoot. Is this all workflows or just some ?

Comment: @JamesRandal I republished the workflow but still get the same error while starting. Its occurring for all workflows.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate and re-activate the Workflows feature in Site collection features and check again.

Strat workflow with other account instead of system account and compare the results.

Check ULS log to find the detailed information.

Per my resaerch, after any of the September 2018 .NET Framework security updates to resolve CVE-2018-8421 (.NET Framework Remote Code Execution Vulnerability) are applied, SharePoint out-of-the-box workflows stop working.

Refer to the following article:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update

Comment: Chen The below are the KB articles which was recently updated in the server. Would this updates causes any issues?
KB4462915
KB4467106
KB4474419
KB4480960
KB4493448
KB4503269
KB4507456
KB4536952
KB4534310
KB4343205
KB4530677
KB4457145
KB4471328
KB4486564